# How to send values to a pipe?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-pipe

This is the code:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products | mypipe : product.productColor">
      <label>{{product.productName}}</label>
</div>
```

Is it possible to send the product color to the pipe? I get `undefined` when printing on the console.

I have tried by **interpolation** like the next code but no success
:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products | mypipe : {{product.productColor}}">
      <label>{{product.productName}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want `mypipe` to filter my products by any product propriety, in this case `productColor`. `mypipe` also would receive a second param to be able to filter, the color in this case (eg. Blue)

Comment: How is this `let product of products | mypipe : product.productColor` supposed to work? `product` doesn't exist when `products` is piped to `mypipe`, because `mypipe` should be applied in order for `product` to exist. This is chicken-egg dilemma and also XY problem. Please, provide all relevant source code and revise the question, so it would reflect real problem and not the way you expect it to be solved (it won't work anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for a solution to this but couldn't find one. Instead I chose to handle the array, in your case products in the component class. Whatever logic you want to execute with your pipe, write a method which gives you a filtered list and use that to display in the UI until you get an answer to this.